# Output Value Of Neural Network Does Not Arrive To Desired Values

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I made a neural network that also have Back Propagation.it has  5 nodes in input layer,6 nodes in hidden layer,1 node in output layer and have random weights and i use `sigmoid` as activation function.

i have two set of data for input.

for example :

```
13.5 22.27 0 0 0          desired value=0.02
7 19 4 7 2                desired value=0.03
```

now i train the network with 5000 iteration or iteration will stop if the error

value(`desired - calculated output value`) is less than or equal to 0.001.

the output value of first iteration for each input set is about 60 And it will decrease in each iteration.

now the problem is that the second set of inputs(that has desired value of 0.03),cause to stop iteration because of calculated output value of 3.001 but the first set of inputs did not arrived to desired value of it(that is 0.02) and its output is about 0.03 .

**EDITED :**

I used `LMS` algorithm andchanged the error threshold 0.00001 to find correct error value,but now output value of last iteration for both 0.03 and 0.02 desired value is between 0.023 and 0.027 and that is incorrect yet.

Answer (score 1):

For your error value stop threshold, you should take the error on one epoch (Sum of every error of all your dataset) and not only on one member of you dataset. With this you will have to increase the value of your error threshold but it will force your neural network to do a good classification on all your example and not only on some example.

Comment: thanks,you mean i should sum the error of both input sets for error stop threshold?

Comment: Well normally before updating the weight of your neural network, you have to go through all the dataset. Your problem is that your stop threshold is compute only on one "line" of your dataset and not the entire dataset. So you should sum the error for each line and from here say that the all error need to be less than x.

If you have 1000, let's say that you maybe want a threshold of less than 1000*0.01 more or less. You should try to print your error based on the number of epoch and see what's happening.

Comment: i tested,sumOferror can not be less than 0.020,for example output for first set is about 0.029(desired =0.020 ) and the second set is about 0.041(desired = 0.030).so it is not good way.is there any other way?thanks